# How to show a modal dialog box after clicking "Open" button of a file uploader

Tags: javascript

On clicking browse button of the uploader, both File open dialog box and my modal dialog box
is appearing at the same time.

I need to show the dialog box only after clicking "Open " button of the file dialog box.

Any help will be appreciated

Thank u

Comment: I don't think you can prevent the 'file-open' dialog box appearing with the standard  `<input type="file">`.  If you want any other behaviour, you'll need to emulate the file uploader using `<input type="text">` and `<input type="button" onclick="show-dialog">`